# PL/SQL procedure stuck

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following scenario:

Java servlet calls PL/SQL procedure and waits for return value.
The PL/SQL procedure calls other PL/SQL procedures that do a series of updates, inserts and commits. When everything completes the initial PL/SQL procedure writes a log using pragma and returns 1 if successful.

The problem is that on one environment everything works fine and on another environment the PL/SQL procedure remains stuck(same code and data on both environments).

PL/SQL procedure ex:

```
PROCEDURE Export_1511_PDH_Physic ( o_ErrorCode OUT NUMBER,
                                   o_ErrorText OUT VARCHAR2,
                                   o_Resultat  OUT NUMBER) is

  GlobalExportID NUMBER;
BEGIN
     ASYNCLOG ('Export_1511_PDH_Physic', 'Started');--Pragma writing logs

     GlobalExportID :=0;
     o_Resultat := 0;
     select nvl(max(exportid),0) into GlobalExportID from async.MaxNodeList;

     GlobalExportID := GlobalExportID + 1;
     upd_JRLExport('1511Max Export', GlobalExportID, 0);--Pragma writing logs

     pkggato.MaxIRM_DoExport(GlobalExportID); ---more pl/sql procedures(update, insert...)

   o_Resultat := o_Resultat+1;
```

Everithing printed ok below.

```
   pkgdebug.writelog('o_ErrorCode - ' || o_ErrorCode,'Info');
   pkgdebug.writelog('o_ErrorTex - ' || o_ErrorText,'Info');
   pkgdebug.writelog('o_Resultat - ' || o_Resultat,'Info');
```

The below logs are printed fine.

```
   ASYNCLOG ('Export_1511_PDH_Physic', 'Finished'); --Pragma writing logs
   upd_JRLExport('1511Max Export', GlobalExportID, 1); --Pragma writing logs
END;
```

If a do a DB restart everything works fine on the 1st run.
Any idea on how to debug this?

```
PROCEDURE upd_JRLExport(pis_export_type   ASYNC_JRLEXPORT.EXPORTTYPE%TYPE,
                           pin_export_no     ASYNC_JRLEXPORT.NO_EXPORT%TYPE,
                           pin_start_end_flg NUMBER, --0: Start / 1: End
                           pin_status        ASYNC_JRLEXPORT.STATUS%TYPE DEFAULT NULL)
   IS
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
      ld_now   DATE;
   BEGIN
      SELECT SYSDATE
      INTO ld_now
      FROM DUAL;

      UPDATE ASYNC_JRLEXPORT
      SET START_DATE = DECODE(pin_start_end_flg, 0, ld_now, START_DATE),
         END_DATE = DECODE(pin_start_end_flg, 1, ld_now, END_DATE),
         NO_EXPORT = NVL(pin_export_no, NO_EXPORT),
         STATUS = NVL(pin_status, STATUS)
      WHERE EXPORTTYPE = pis_export_type;

      COMMIT;
END upd_JRLExport;
```

Thanks,
Catalin.

Comment: Can you please specify where does the code remain stuck? Also, which are the differences (if any) between the two environments?

Comment: Everything is printed but the procedure doesn't return anything. I ran it manually from PL/SQL and it keeps running even though there are no running queries on that specific schema. The two environments should be identical... but there might be different DB settings of which I'm not aware.

Comment: what does `upd_JRLExport` actually do? inserts something in the DB?

Comment: updated the question with the procedure

Comment: Does the procedure writes this entry `--Pragma writing logs` at the beginning of the procedure or at the and ? Could be that `upd_JRLExport('` writes the message to the log ant then gets stuck.

Comment: First of all check for locks (if procedure never finishes). Views v$locked_object, dba_objects/all_objects and v$session will help.

Comment: @krokodilko, it writes on both ends, beginning and end

Comment: I discovered another thing which might help, I limited two updates that are executed at some point by the procedure (limited them from 50k updates to 1) and it works fine. So...I don't think there is a problem with objects being locked. Is there a memory limitation per running code?

Comment: How did you limit that ? A can't see any limit in the code You have shown in the question. And why "two updates"? I can only see one update in the code, is there any update elsewhere you haven't shown ?

Comment: This procedure does a lot of inserts and updates into different tables 'pkggato.MaxIRM_DoExport(GlobalExportID)' and it's called by the previous code. There are no locks on the schema, everything is printed as it should. I didn't put all the code because there are a lot of lines. By coincidence I noticed that limiting those 2 updates to just one row then evreything works but I don't understand the connection.

Comment: Did you try to trace session in question? Is it possible that it is just very slow on that particular environment e.g. due to bad statistics?

Comment: Yes, traced it, it's not slower. Everything looks normal except the thing that it doesn't end, it just hangs without any object being locked.....

Comment: Based on the logs can you find out where exactly it got stuck? If no, add more log messages/instrument your code. Since we cannot see all the code we have no idea what is happening and where is it happening. You said that everything is printed, but the procedure doesn't return anything - what is printed? Are you using dbms_output.put_line to write messages?

Comment: There is nothing stuck, I checked and re checked. I think it's a network/firewall issue because I called the procedure directly from the DB server and it's executed successfully. Something is blocking the connection after a period of time but the weird thing is that I don't get disconnected ... it's like the twilight zone

Comment: Finally, the problem was solved. It was due to the fact that the client modified the firewall rules and set it to silently drop the connections after 30 minutes of idle. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
PROCEDURE upd_JRLExport(pis_export_type   ASYNC_JRLEXPORT.EXPORTTYPE%TYPE,
                           pin_export_no     ASYNC_JRLEXPORT.NO_EXPORT%TYPE,
                           pin_start_end_flg NUMBER, --0: Start / 1: End
                           pin_status        ASYNC_JRLEXPORT.STATUS%TYPE DEFAULT NULL)
   IS
 V_ERRORMESSAGE varchar2(2000);
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
      ld_now   DATE;
   BEGIN
      SELECT SYSDATE
      INTO ld_now
      FROM DUAL;

      UPDATE ASYNC_JRLEXPORT
      SET START_DATE = DECODE(pin_start_end_flg, 0, ld_now, START_DATE),
         END_DATE = DECODE(pin_start_end_flg, 1, ld_now, END_DATE),
         NO_EXPORT = NVL(pin_export_no, NO_EXPORT),
         STATUS = NVL(pin_status, STATUS)
      WHERE EXPORTTYPE = pis_export_type;

      COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      V_ERRORMESSAGE := SQLERRM;
     dbms_output.put_line('NO DATA FOUND :' || V_ERRORMESSAGE);
       RAISE;
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
   V_ERRORMESSAGE := SQLERRM;
   dbms_output.put_line('OTHER ERROR :' || V_ERRORMESSAGE);
     RAISE;

END upd_JRLExport;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).